# how to get scrollinghotspot to show

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to implement the autoscroll feature seen here http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/#quickdemo

on my testsite http://hardis.synology.me/portalen/main.php?id=2

I am however stuck and don't understand what the problem might be, here's my code:

```
<div  id="makeMeScrollable" class="main" >
            <?php
                $sql26 = "SELECT * FROM MCI ORDER BY Id_kund DESC";  // WHERE Id_kund desc Matningstyp ='$Matningstyp' AND/OR Affarsomrade ='$Affarsomrade' AND/OR Byra ='$Byra'
                $result26 = mysql_query($sql26) or die (mysql_error());  
                while ($row26 = mysql_fetch_array($result26)) 
                { 
                if($row26["Kampanj"] <= 20){
                    $star = 1;
                }
                    elseif($row26["Kampanj"] <= 30){
                        $star = 2;
                    }
                    elseif($row26["Kampanj"] <= 40){
                        $star = 3;
                    }
                    elseif($row26["Kampanj"] <= 50){
                        $star = 4;
                    }
                    else{
                        $star = 5;
                    }   $classname = ($first == $row26['Id']) ? 'focused' : 'normal';
                        echo "<div style=\"margin:5px 10px;\" data-produktkategori='{$row26[Produktkategori]}' data-id='{$row26[Id]}' class='abc $classname'><a class='infoXXXYYY' href='http://hardis.synology.me/portalen/main.php?id=2&scroll=".$row26[Id]."'><img src=\"foretag/Effectris/Presentationer/{$test}/".$row26["Matningsnamn"]."/enheter/1.png\" wIdth=\"150\" height=\"120\" style=\"position: relative;\">
                                <div style=\"background:black;opacity:0.6;width:150px;height:50px;position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;\"></div>
                                <img src=\"img/stars/STARS2/3/$star.png\" style=\"position: absolute;  bottom: 35px; left: 3px;width:70px;z-index:1111;\"> <H6 style=\"font-size:11px;color:white;position: absolute;bottom: 20px; left: 5px;z-index:3311;\">".date("M,Y", strtotime($row26['Datum_formatning']))."</H6>
                                <H6 style=\"font-size:11px;color:white;position: absolute;bottom: 5px; left: 5px;z-index:3311;\">".$row26['Kampanjnamn']."</H6> 
                                <div class='mask'>
                                        <h2 style=\"text-transform: uppercase;color: WHITE;width:120px;text-align: LEFT;position: relative;font-size: 15px;border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);background: transparent;margin: 0px 10px;padding: 5px;\">".$row26["Matningsnamn"]."</h2>
                                        <p>Kanal: <b>".$row26['Kanal']."</b></p>
                                        <p>Intentionsförflyttning: <br \><b>".$row26['Nyfikenhet']." enheter</b> </p>

                                </div></a>
                            </div>";
                        } ;
                    ?>
                </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
        manualContinuousScrolling: true,
        autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was easy... I forgot to link to the smoothscrolldiv.css... All is fine now :)